# React Router v4 Group of Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to create a Route Group to validate each route with the first Component. But it may not be possible. Because React read just the first group, I also tried it with React.Fragment, but the same thing happens

I created a Group of Routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import _ from 'lodash';

export const PathGroup = (pathGroup, sadas) => {
    const Template = pathGroup.template;

    return (
        { _.map(pathGroup.children, (pathRoute, key) => {
            const { component, path, exact, ...another } = pathRoute.props;
            return (
                <Route
                    exact
                    path={path}
                    key={key}
                    render={ (route) => <Template
                        component={component}
                        route={route}
                        {...another}
                    />}
                />
            )
        }) }
    );
};

export const Path = (path) => {
    return <React.Fragment/>
};
```

To print the routes by group in this way:

```
render() {
    const user = this.props.user;
    if (!user.verified) { return(<div>Loading...</div>); }
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <PathGroup template={PublicLayout} >
                    <Path exact path='/contact' component={Contact}  user={user}/>
                    <Path exact path='/' component={Home}  user={user} />
                </PathGroup>
                <PathGroup template={PrivateLayout} verify={this.props.user.logged}  redirectFalse="/projects" >
                    <Path exact path='/profile' component={Profile}  user={user} />
                    <Path exact path='/posts' component={Posts}  user={user} />
                    <Path exact path='/posts/:idPost' component={Post}  user={user} />
                </PathGroup>
                <PathGroup template={Login} verify={this.props.user.logged} redirectTrue="/projects"  >
                    <Path exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                </PathGroup>
                <Route component={ NotFound } />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

But when I run the app it shows just the first group

[image]

Also I tried with React.Fragment, but happens the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer you want, but if you want to have a fallback page for each base `route`, the easiest way is to use nested `switch`.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = props => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={props.match.url + "/1"} exact render={() => <h1>Home 1</h1>} />
      <Route path={props.match.url + "/2"} exact render={() => <h1>Home 2</h1>} />
      <Route render={() => <h1>Home 404</h1>} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

const Post = props => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={props.match.url + "/1"} exact render={() => <h1>Post 1</h1>} />
      <Route path={props.match.url + "/2"} exact render={() => <h1>Post 2</h1>} />
      <Route render={() => <h1>Post 404</h1>} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/post" component={Post} />
          <Route render={() => <h1>404</h1>} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

- The authentication can be done in each root route component, and then redirect to login page.
- Query parameter also can be used, so the same route can handle multiple ids.

Eg: `<Route path={this.props.match.url + '/:id'} exact component={Post} />` and then, in Post component, using `const { id } = this.props.match.params` to get the id.

There is the [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/p38qo95rzj).

Comment: Thank you, but the idea is to make some similar to [Laravel Middleware ](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-middleware). To validate the group of routes, not route by route.

Comment: @albertcito Does your link relate to `react-router-dom`? I'm not aware react-router has this Middleware idea, but I might be wrong. However, you can always write `Home` and `Post` classes into a high order function and past its `props` into `children` component (similar to `withRouter` function), but that just add an extra layer of complexity in your code.